# Python Selenium Script Having Trouble Finding Button on Modal

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Our developer that does python left and I've been assigned the task of learning how to use the language. On top of that we can't find his source code so I'm having to rebuild the code from scratch.  I have no experience in python and have spent all morning trying to find the answer to this. I realize there's 100 other questions similar to this and I promise I've looked through most of them.

I'm scraping a site and after logging in a modal is popping up forcing me to click a button to exit it. The button doesn't have an ID so I'm trying to find it by text. I've tried using XPATH, LINK_TEXT, and a couple of other things.  Below is my code and some screenshots that I hope help identify what I'm doing wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

I think this is a temporary modal so I'm trying to set up the code to look for my "real" button first. If it can't find it then throw the exception and look for the modal button.

```
try:
    srch = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "1744")))
    srch.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#NoSuchElementException thrown if not present
except:
    btn_text = "Don't ask again"
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()=\"" + btn_text + "\"]"))).click()
```

This is giving me the following error while debugging:

[image]

I'm trying to select the Don't ask again button to close the modal. Here's what I see when I inspect it:

[image]

Curiously though, if I just start by inspecting the modal "from the beginning", when I drill down to where the button is it's properties don't come up, this is as far down as it goes:

[image]

And this is where I'm stuck. Does anybody have any suggestions?

EDIT:  I'm adding the entire error that I'm getting below:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you working on? And please share the entire error (you cut it) and if possible more page HTML if it is not possible to share the page link

Comment: I can't share a link, it contains sensitive payroll data.  The part of the error that I cut out was the strack trace, but I can edit and include if you think that wouldhelp?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this can help

Comment: added at the end of the OP

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the real page entire HTML we can only guess, so as a first guess I would suggest instead of this

```
btn_text = "Don't ask again"
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()=\"" + btn_text + "\"]"))).click()
```

I'd try this:

```py
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'ask again')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and am receiving the same error.  I just posted the entire error at the end of the OP.  Would it help if I Viewed Page Source and copy and pasted it onto here? I can't share a link because it contains sensitive payroll data.

Comment: In case you can past the entire HTML this can help. Not 100% sure, but possibly. Can you check if `//a[contains(.,'ask again')]` matches an element there and it is a unique locator i.e. matches single element only?